# Fragment lifecycle when use in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In `ViewPager` with `TableLayout`, I have 5 fragments. I click on Fragment-3, `setUserVisibleHint = true`. `Button` on Fragment-3 clicked, replace or add another fragment. Not getting any event on Fragment-3, when click back. I want to do some action when user clicks back.

```
 public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ThreeFragment newInstance() {
        ThreeFragment fragment = new ThreeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("onResume", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("onPause", "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d("onCreateView", "onCreateView");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.txt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
                BlankFragment fragment2 = BlankFragment.newInstance();
                fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack("abc");
                fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction2.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        Log.d("setUserVisibleHint", "setUserVisibleHint :: " + isVisibleToUser);
    }
}
```

NewFragment :

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance() {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you have button on Fragment-3 and when user click this butoon it take him to anthor Fragment? then you want when user click back button in the new Fragment take him back to Fragment-3?

Comment: Open new fragment and back navigation handled. When clicks back from new fragment, Fragment-3 don't get any lifecycle event to identify that Fragment-3 is now visible

Comment: now i understand you please share you  Fragment-3 and the new  Fragment code to make it easy to me to help you

Comment: I have added the code bro.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily handle it in the new fragment

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
   @Override
   public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        //do what you wnt to do when the user prees back
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
} );
```

before return true; do what you want to do when the user press back
and u can use

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

to hide the last fragment and show the pre one

Comment: Bro. if only one navigation would there I could handle it. But there are many navigations to different fragments. I posted just for an example

Comment: what you want to do exactly when back button pressed?

Comment: The transactions list needs to update and other UI updation, everytime when back press.

Comment: just copy onKey method on all of your fragment and update UI as u like in every fragment back pressed